# PHP 5.4 fail to load mysql or pgsql database on windows 7

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I download PHP5.4 , apache 2.2, and Postgres 9.1 separately..

my apache and php works fine, code like phpinfo() was run normally in browser.

but i cannot call function like pg_connect / mysql_connect.

it said "Call to undefined function pg_connect() in bla bla"

i check info phpinfo() and no word appear about mysql or pqsql.

i go to dir c:php\php.ini (developer) and change ;extension=php_mysql.dll to extension=php_mysql.dll (also for pgsql and their pdo)

i surf many forum and got nothing, can anyone help me what must i do?

**SOLVED** : just need to change PHP.ini.production or development to php.ini

Comment: You have to download MySQL server: http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/uestudio/local_php_mysql_dev_environment.html

Comment: what about pgsql? im want to enabled my pgsql first

Comment: What about downloading that in stead of MySQL ? ;) http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/

Comment: error said "Call to undefined function pg_connect()", so if the problem is at the DB, then error messages should be different?

Comment: open the php.ini file and give the username and password of your mysql or pgsql database.

Comment: its the further problem, now i cannot call function to connect DB

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment the extension=php_pgsql.dll and extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll

Comment: How is this different from *change ;extension=php_mysql.dll to extension=php_mysql.dll*?

Answer (score 0):

The `extension_dir` directive in `phpinfo()`'s output should say `ext`. If it doesn't:

- You haven't set it
- You've edited the wrong file
- You haven't restarted Apache
- You're getting a startup error

---

**Edit:** your first mention to **php.ini (developer)** made me think it was just a reference to what template you used to create the `php.ini` file. Now I have the impression that you're actually editing the templates themselves:

- `php.ini-development`
- `php.ini-production`

You have to choose a template and **copy** it as `php.ini`. This file path must match what you see at *Loaded Configuration File* in `phpinfo()`.

Comment: i saw at phpinfo(), local and master value in directive extension_dir is C:\php

Comment: what do you mean with ext?

Comment: Just type those three letters `e`, `x` and `t` in the `extension_dir` directive, like: `extension_dir = "ext"`. In fact, you probably just need to uncomment it.

Comment: i found it and i uncomment extension_dir, but in phpinfo() its stuck with c:\php ....

i change php.ini at c:\php (both developer and production)
then restart apache (no error)